# How to use permutation test to find significant outcomes from many fisher exact tests

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I am reading from [this](https://stanford.edu/class/gene210/files/gwas-howto.pdf) where they mention running 500K fisher exact test to find significant associations between different DNA changes and a phenotype.

They also mention that Bonferroni, Benjamini, and FDR can be used to set a significance threshold, which I think I understand.

What I don't get is that they say permutation can also be used to set a significance threshold. How can you use permutation on fisher exact test output to set a significance threshold?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to speculate they mean without giving a citation or reference, but they may be referring to the Westfall-Young method which is a permutation based method.  I did just answer a question at CV where I suggested using permutation testing (empirical p-value testing), which is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519219/why-do-parameters-go-untested-in-machine-learning/519227#519227).